# Mapping 2 different product JSON data formats

Tags: typescript

I fetch various suppliers' products, Each supplier has different product model. I have figured out that in order to refer and extract data from supplier's model I have to create some sort of mapping. What I am having difficulty with is creating a deeper mapping e.g. my product has a single `price` property where as my supplier `prices.USD`. What would be a decent way to map the deeper properties so, that the parsing work is simple?

My `Product` type

```
type Product = {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Supplier 1 product type

```
type Supplier1Product = { 
  id: string
  product_name: string;
  product_description: string;
  prices: {
    EUR: number;
    USD: number;
  }
}
```

My mapping attempt

```
const mapping = {
  name: 'product_name',
  description: 'product_description',
  price: 'prices.USD',
}
```

I want to be able to get the values in a similar fashion to this

```
const productPrice = supplierProduct[mapping.price];
```

**edit**
Ideally it is a solution I can store in a database. I thought about an object as I can store it as a JSON.

Comment: Perhaps have a mapping function that receives the supplier product and return your model. Example:
`const supplierA = (supplierAProduct) => ({ name: supplierAProduct.name, price: supplierAProduct.price.USD })
const supplierB = (supplierBProduct) => ({ name: supplierBProduct.name, price: supplierBProduct.cost})`

Comment: @origeva thanks, I did think of something similar but I thought about storing the mapping in a database. Is there an alternative to that I can store per supplier?